# iFrame a specific part of a page?

Tags: iframe

I would like to target a specific part of a page to show in an iFrame. I know that this is possible as I found a solution for some while ago, but I lost the link and can't seem to find it on google anymore.

Answer (score 2):

If the part of the page contains a link with a name you can do

```
<iframe src="page.html#link_name"></iframe>
```

If the page doesn't have links like these [you can scroll the iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript)