# Target specific div after form submit into iframe.

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, html

Here is my set up...

I have two pages, index.html and cart.html.   I have a form on index.html that, when submitted loads cart.html in a pop-up iframe.  That works fine.

When I load the cart.html into the iframe it loads the entire cart.html page, showing the header/menu/background that is the same as the index.html.  But that's a problem, I need to be able to load the cart.html into the iframe, but then target a div with an ID of 'cart-content'.  I need only that div to show and not the entire page.

A work around, would be to just stylize cart.html so it fits in the iframe without and of it's headers/menus/backgrounds, but I need to be able to visit cart.html outside of the iframe.

here is my form:

```
<form id="product-form" method="post" action="/cart">
<!-- BIG CARTEL CONTENT, NOT IMPORTANT -->
</form>
```

I am using a jQuery plugin, FaceBox to open the iFrame.  Here is it's code:

```
jQuery('#product-form').submit(function() {
    jQuery.facebox('<iframe name="targetbox"></iframe>');
    return true;
}).prop('target','target box')
```

So in the form I need it's action to be something like "/cart#cart-content"  Make sense?  Hope someone can help!  Thanks

Comment: What's `.prop('target','target box')`??

Comment: It's apart of the Facebox code to load the iframe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out: [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Basically, use the load function to load up the cart.html page, and select the div off that page you want to display - i.e.

`$('#popUpDiv').load('path-to-my-page/cart.html #divToDisplay')`

In this case, #divToDisplay is the ID of the piece of cart.html you want to load into the popup.

Note The last sentance of Pointy's answer -

> There may be other things you need to do, and a significant difference
>   is that the content will become part of the main page instead of being
>   segregated into a separate window.

You might need to account for this if you're submitting from the loaded div.

HTH

Comment: But how do I load that cart.html into the iframe if I have to remove it from the form?

Comment: In this case you wouldn't be using an iframe. the content would load directly into a div (the pop up div) on your page.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I decided to stick with iFrames and just make any link on the page that directs to the cart to open in an iFrame.  You answer was correct thought if I was to do it that way.  Thanks