# Iframes in HTML noob

Tags: html, iframe

My (fan) website has this code so far. I want the crop I have specified (-360px on the top and -50px to apply to each iframe, but no matter WHAT I do the other three iframes do not have the crop). Is there a way to make the crop apply to all the iframes? I am completely lost. :(

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; 
margin-top: -360px; 
margin-left: -50px;">
<iframe src="http://dragcave.net/view/XD" frameborder="0" width="750" height="450" " scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://dragcave.net/locations/XD" frameborder="0" width="750" height="450" " scrolling="no"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://dragcave.net/locations/XD" frameborder="0" width="750" height="450" " scrolling="no"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: By 'crop' do you mean you want to reduce the size of the iframes? If so, margin is not what you want.

Comment: By crop I mean remove certain aspects of the webpage, i.e. part of the top and right/left of the frame so it's not displayed.

Comment: I think you'll have to define them in the individual page's css

Answer (score 0):

iFrames only show the whole page, there's not really any way for you to only show part of a page in an iframe.

What you need to do is some jquery trickery, which you can find here: [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Comment: If I barely know anything about HTML, I know nothing about jquery: where I put it/how to load a 'fragment' and whether it works for multiple fragments and how to integrate it into div. The margin I posted works for the first iFrame, I think the best option is just to somehow make it apply to the second and the third iframe if it's actually possible. x_x Just looking at the link, the part about jquery just makes absolutely no sense to me. I tried using it and it just comes up with a blank page. Particularly the part about the searched tag, I didn't search any tags? :/