# html load specific div from external url into jquery dialog

Tags: jquery, html, dialog, external

I could display the entire external url in a dialog but what I want is to display content from a specific div of the external url. Any advices??

Here is what I have done..

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body{ font-size: 12px; font-family: Arial; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>


<button id="dialog_trigger">Open The Dialog</button>

<div id="dialog" style="display:none;" title="Dialog Title">
<iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" width="700" height="700" src="someblogurl">
</iframe>
</div>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
$( "#dialog_trigger" ).click(function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
});
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    position: 'center' ,
    title: 'Listing Table',
    draggable: false,
    width : 500,
    height : 500,
    resizable : true,
    modal : true,
});


  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Comment: thanks iframe works! however, if there would be any changes to the content of the external url then the iframe properties would have to change accordingly as well.. Is there better way to do it? I have tried using jquery Loading Page Fragments but it couldn't work.