# Load specific div in iframe from external site in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Problem Question -

How to load a specific div from the external site into the iframe? I am aware of the Same Origin Policy and external Site belongs to me. How would I do this in AngularJs.

I looked for this but most of the answers are in  jQuery only.

Thanks for the help

**Update 1**

Let me be more specific. For instance if you use iframe, it gives you access to everything. But I only want a Particular DIV of of this external URL.

```
<iframe style="border: 0" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://localhost:8888/">
```

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20045150/angular-js-how-to-set-an-iframe-src-attribute-from-a-variable

Comment: I did, it is not what I am after. Please read my question. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify (or show a jQuery example) of what you mean by load a div from external site into iframe?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page @NewDev this is the post of jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, blindly and thoughtlessly using jQuery will not play nice with Angular. This is not so much because of jQuery - the library, but more so because Angular and jQuery promote different programming paradigms.

Nevertheless, jQuery is a toolbox, and one such tool is `jQuery.load()`.

The best way, in my mind, to make it work with Angular is to create a directive that uses `jQuery.load()`:

```
.directive("load", function($compile){
  return {
    restrict: "A",
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){

      attrs.$observe('load', function(newValue){
        elem.load(newValue, null, function(){

          // compile the newly imported div
          $compile(elem.contents())(scope);

          // need to force $digest, since this is outside of Angular digest cycle
          scope.$digest();
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Then you could use it like so:

```
<div load="foo.html #id"></div>
```

or,

```
<div load="{{urlWithId}}"></div>
```

Be sure to load jQuery before Angular, otherwise `.load` will not be defined.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TocihwX2xRNGqPyolAiH?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for putting so much time in this. I will give this a try :).

Comment: I tried it out but somehow <div load="{{urlWithId}}"></div> does not work,neither it gives out any error in console. Does it worked for you ?

Comment: thanks :). One last question- For instance I make a ajax call to external URL and get the content of the website. Will this be useful as this is finding DOM in the HTML templates?. I am getting everything in Angular Controller and can see DOM of external URL , what i want to do now is just get specific Form ID and display in my page. Is this something you can help me with please?

Comment: That sounds like a separate question and probably needs more details. Short of that, you could follow the concepts in my answer to solve this case.

Comment: yup, I have been trying but only problem is could not get the Form displayed from controller to view. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hi I created new question. If you have a time please have a look.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26477958/display-div-from-response-in-angularjs thanks :)