# iframe fullscreen 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I've managed to do a Iframe that shows **only certain part of the page** with this code:

```
<div id="divContainer" style="display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
     <div id="frameContainer" style="overflow:hidden;">
          <iframe src="http://www.cofm.es/informacion-corporativa/buscador-farmacias" scrolling="no" style="width: 1000px; height: 750px; margin-top: -330px; margin-left: -250px;" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe><br />

</div>
```

Source: [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Now what I'm trying to do is to make the Iframe **show on the 100% width on the screen**. I've been able to do this with images with this code:

```
<img style="width: 100%; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; " src="http://i.ytimg.com/vi/ROv863DuJu4/maxresdefault.jpg" />
```

I'm trying to make the iframe adapt to the screen size like the image does.

Comment: you need to make the iframe 100% width

Comment: I tried with no luck... Can you show me how with the example I provided?

Answer (score 0):

Iframe is an inline element - You need to set css " display:block " - then you can make it 100% and it will scale - Hope this helps. 
here is an example - you would have to set the containing element to full width as well..

```
<iframe style='display:block;width:100%' src='http://someurl.com'></iframe> 

  https://jsfiddle.net/cqgfqgqk/
```

Comment: If its not to much to ask, could you give an example of a iframe that shows certain part of a page and also has 100% width? I tried with display block and nothing