# Positioning an iFrames content

Tags: html, css, iframe

**I'd like to use an iFrame to display the following page:** http://www.workbooks.com/training/courses

I just want to show the page content, not the top or left navigation/internal ads.

I've tried the following:

```
<iframe scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.workbooks.com/training/courses" allowtransparency="true" style="height:100%;width:75%;">
</iframe>
```

Instead of it showing 75% of the contents width it's reducing the overall width of the iFrame.

Please advise.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe is not a suitable option for this task, you can try jquery.

```
<div id = "showContent"></div>

<button id = "btn" onclick="showit()">Show info from another page.</button>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(){
        $('#showContent').load('http://mywebs.com');
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Mohit, Unfortunately I currently know nothing of Javascript or Jquery. When I tried your solution it simply displayed the line as a <p>. How can I get the page to read it instead?

Comment: P.S. Is the idea with this that I create a div i.e. with the i.d. #showContent with the content I want to show and the load will only display this div?

Comment: Thanks Mohit. Having trouble with this so will re-raise as a JQuery issue.

Comment: @StackOver let me know wat the trouble is