# jQuery .load not loading button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to load a button from another page onto my page using jQuery. I've been following theinstructions detailed in the following url and havent beeen able to get it to work. I am still a bit new to jQuery so i may have small mistakes. Anything will help.  [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script> $("#m").load('https://www.minds.com/theantimedia .minds-subscribe-button');
</script>

<div id="m"></div>
```

Update: I've been running it by opening it from an html file in my browser. I dont know if its like php and wont work. Also if i've broken any rules by posting this please warn me and i'll delete this question. Thanks!

Comment: You need to close your `<script>` tag, like this `</script>`.

Comment: It is closed. Look at the next line.

Comment: Not the jquery script tag.

Comment: Oh, i see haha, sorry. I'll fix that and see if it works

Comment: It still doesnt work

Comment: Also, close your quote. in the `load` method.

Comment: And load jquery first then use it

Comment: And, you might want to get rid of the extra space before the `.minds-subscribe-button` just in case.

Comment: Just tested that. I also updated the code above. It still doesnt work. I just get a blank page.

Comment: `I've been running it by opening it from an html file in my browser`, that might be your answer.  It's the same as PHP, because a browser is a browser, the backend make's no difference..  There are plenty of way of serving local files, if you using node.js, you could just npm install serve, or something similar.

Comment: Ah, ok. Thank you! I didnt know that.