# Is it possible to include a particular division of another website using iframe in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I know it is possible to display a complete website using iframe. But the problem is coming to display a particular  tag of another website using iframe
Is there any other way of displaying particular division of another website using/not using iframe in HTML??

Comment: Visit the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page. It might help you because there are possible solutions for your problem.