# Replicate portion of webpage in new site (tips for injecting dom and style scoping)

Tags: css, scope, vue.js, html

### Scenario

Suppose I have a web service capable of fetching a webpage and its static assets (e.g. using PhantomJS).  I want to be able to serve the static DOM sub-structure (e.g. everything under the `#content div`) along with its styling to a new site that shows the extracted webpage on the left side along with the amazing results of my super-amazing awesome machine-learning algorithm for extracting information from webpages on the other side.

### Question

Supposing I can send down the HTML sub-structure, CSS, and other asset files down from the server, how do I go about injecting the HTML substructure into a `div` on my page while scoping the styling?

```
<!-- partially modified content pulled from another site -->
<div id="content">
  <!-- I might pull stylesheets from head of source site -->
  <!-- and inject them in content?  Or should I just keep -->
  <!-- track of styles separately and manually inject them? -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
  <img src="new/path/to/static/resource/that/i/saved"/>
</div>


<!-- my own web page with stuff etc -->
<div id="left">
  <!-- INSERT CONTENT DIV AND OTHER ASSETS HERE -->
</div>
<div id="right">
  <!-- here I have Vue components and other page interaction stuff -->
</div>
```

---

Currently I'm using `VueJS` for my webpage.  I know I can do style scoping using Vue components -- maybe there is a way to leverage that?  But I really want to know how to solve this problem in a general, framework-agnostic way.  I'm too paralyzed by all these things I think could go wrong to even start...

Comment: Maybe use an iframe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page

Comment: Have you tried using [iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe)?

Comment: I believe `iframe` will not work because I only want to show a specific portion of the page?