# iframe to display a single div

Tags: iframe

Any idea how an iframe (or alternate solution) can be used to display a single div of a public website? We would like to display the GDAX trading charts on a monitor in the office. Looking at the public facing gdax exchange, the  contains all the charts, orderbook, history, etc., but excludes the left login bar and the top white bar.[View Exchange](https://www.gdax.com/trade/BTC-USD) We want to cut out the unnecessary stuff and full screen the browser. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Comment: I don't think you're gonna have much luck with an iframe (Same Origin Policy won't let you do much anyway; at most some CSS clipping to only show a rectangular part of the page would perhaps be possible, if you know the dimensions and they are static), and would therefor try with a user stylesheet for that page/domain configured in the browser first, that removes all unwanted clutter by setting it to `display:none`.

Comment: That site sends `x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN` btw., so to get it displayed in an iframe to begin with you'd need a browser extension to override that (not out of the question of course in your scenario, but something to keep in mind.)

Comment: Hmm... Any other workarounds you can think of not using iframes?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest user scripts [Userscripts (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Userscript)

Another option would be use a "translation" proxy: basically a proxy that parses the response and forwards a modified response to the user.