# how to fetch the content within <table> tag from an website

Tags: javascript, php, html

I used this code to fetch all the content of the website page.

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://berojgarjobs.com/forms/AirForceAFCAT.php');  echo $url;
```

This code shows all the content of the website but i want only those content
which is within `<table></table>` tag.
you can use **javascript** ,**php**,**curl** any to fetch the particular content within the tag from any website

suggest the answer if you can?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272151/7415107

Comment: Try it by yourself, we won't write a code for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [DOMDocument's loadHTML](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($url);
```

Then obtain the TABLE node from that object.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `preg_match_all` function:

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://berojgarjobs.com/forms/AirForceAFCAT.php');
$pattern = "/<table(.*)<\/table>/i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $url, $match);
$table = $match[0][0];
echo $table;
```

There is other way:

```
$url = file_get_contents('https://www.sarkariexam.com/canara-bank-recruitment-2012/994');
$tables = [];
$pos = 0;
do {
    $start = strpos($url, '<table', $pos);
    $end = strpos($url, '</table', $pos);
    if ($end !== false && $start !== false) {
        $tables[] = substr($url, $start, $end - $start + 8);
        $pos = $end;
    }
} while ($end !== false && $start !== false);
```

Comment: this is not work for   $url = file_get_contents('https://www.sarkariexam.com/canara-bank-recruitment-2012/994');
$pattern = "/<table(.*)<\/table>/i";
preg_match_all($pattern, $url, $match);
$table = $match[0][0];
echo $table;