# load specific div from external webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, selenium

I was looking to do something advanced: open multiple user accounts on a specific webpage, to make multiple appointments at the same time so I want to only load or refresh, the appointment div calendar, without refresh whole website. Again it is not my website, just external webpage for appointment

Comment: if ant thing needed i can provide more information Sshots , Capture, CODE

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: the question , how to load this <div> on external webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference a div on another website using an iFrame. The iFrame is used to reference the div on the other website where the calendar of that person is located. You might want to add more information / code examples so that we can help you easier.

```
$('#yourPage').load('wwww.webSiteWithElementYouWant.com #calendarDivIdName');
```

This is a solution with inspiration from Pointy's answer on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page).

**Edit 1**
You *should* be able to target a `class` by using:

`$('#yourPage').load('wwww.webSiteWithElementYouWant.com .calendarDivClassName');`

Comment: thank you but , if the <div> has no ID & i wanna select this <div> by cssclass name , can i do that ? 

<div class="take_appointment">
#div.take_appointment

Comment: See updated answer. with `class` selector in the `.load` function.

Comment: @stupidgeek please let me know if the solution was ok, and mark my answer as accepted if you find it satisfying :)