# load an html from another web in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

they will have some idea to upload an HTML code from an external website in a div

For example get the html of the facebook login:

```
<form id="login_form" action="https://www.facebook.com/login/device-based/regular/login/?login_attempt=1&amp;lwv=110" method="post" novalidate="1" onsubmit=""></from>
```

and show it to me in a `div`

I would like to use an iframe but it would show me the whole web, what I want is for it to show me only a part

Thank you

Comment: This answer may be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16536139/2437278

Answer (score 0):

```
//You can use this for load HTML in a div
$( "#result" ).load( "webpage.html #divId" );
```