# How do I access just the box on this webpage?

Tags: html

First, let me say that I don't know much about HTML. I know how computer programming languages work, but the last time I coded was using COBOL in my job back in 1998.

I am a GeoGebra user. I created a GeoGebra activity for my students, which you can view at the link below.
https://www.geogebra.org/m/jrgv82zv

You can see that the link goes to a webpage in which there is a box in which my activity resides. Around it is some extra stuff. I would like to take that box and put it in a Canvas page. (Canvas is a learning management system.) I saved the webpage as HTML using Chrome, but I can't make out all the stuff in it. I thought I could identify a section of the HTML that I can copy and paste into the content I create for my students, but I can't make out what that would be. Is it just a matter of figuring out what to copy and paste, or does it involve more than that to get the box into my Canvas content?

I know I can just embed the whole page into my Canvas content, but I really just want the box without all the other extra stuff. Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like a simple iframe work for you?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe

For example:

```
<iframe src="demo_iframe.htm" height="200" width="300" title="Iframe Example"></iframe>
```

In your case:

```html
<HTML>
<BODY>
 <iframe src="https://www.geogebra.org/m/jrgv82zv" title="description" style="width:100%; height:100%"> 
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you. That's the backup plan, as I mentioned at the end of of post. The problem is that using iframe the way you did does not include only the box containing the activity I want but the whole webpage.

Comment: @MingHo you'd have to import their JS files and hope it's not obfuscated/generated dynamically.  It might be possible with something like this to use JQuery to load only a portion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page