# I am trying to "cut" a part of an iframe element

Tags: html, css, iframe, jdoodle

I have put an online compiler website inside my website, using an HTML iframe element. Basically, I want the user to compile and write code directly on my website, without opening a separate tab with the online compiler.

Now, I want to know if there is an option to "cut" a part of the website displayed by the iframe element inside my website. Somehow to restrict the user to seeing just the part of that website I want him to see.

I want to mention that I don't want to use any other methods, just the iframe element. Thanks :)

Comment: You can use the `scrolling=no` attribute on the iframe, and set its size to a specific size, if what you want the user to see happens to be at the top of the framed page and has a specific height.  Other than that your options are pretty limited, you can't directly control the contents of a third party iframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [iframe to Only Show a Certain Part of the Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3272071/iframe-to-only-show-a-certain-part-of-the-page)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a iframe you might want to try this (Jquery)

```
$('#target-div').load('http://www.mywebsite.com/portfolio.php #portfolio-sports');
```

From:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3272151/15263184

Comment: Thanks, dude! :D