# Can pages loaded into an iframe from another domain be scrolled via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

If yes, could you please show me an example of how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scrolling an iframe with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript)

Comment: See [CMS's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript/1229879#1229879) in the duplicate - it's not possible to do this across domains.

Answer (score 3):

No. But you can put a large iframe in a small parent div that has CSS `overflow`, and then write to the div's `scrollTop`/`scrollLeft`.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible. You have no control over an iframe from another domain for security reasons.