# Auto scroll top when page loaded using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to scroll the page automatically back to the top when the page is loaded.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(window).scrollTop(0);
        return false;

    });
</script>
```

However, the code does not work.
I have also tried to replace `$(window)` to `$('html, body')`,
sadly it still does not work.

So could anyone advice on this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: This works for me: http://fiddle.jshell.net/aWfQN/show/#foo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    });
</script>
```

The parameters 0,0 are the x and y coördinates.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, however it does not too.
Is it because I have wrapped the page inside an iframe?

Comment: I'm not sure, this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions didn't work for me in Chrome. This is what I had the most success with:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
  $('body').fadeOut(225);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is easier and more reliable if you use this solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:0},800);
</script>
```

In fact some browsers will respond to `'html'` and some to `'body'`.

PS. "800" is the duration of the animation.

Answer (score 0):

This is jQuery safe:

```js
< script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scrollTop(0); 
</script>
```