# What are various ways to display the content within an <iframe> to a different position instead of default?

Tags: html, css, iframe

In other words, I am displaying the content of my Code School account in an  in the education section of my portfolio site. The header from Code School is too large, for my taste, to be displayed on my page.

[image: content in the iframe]

So I either want the page within the iframe to load at a predefined position which I can set in the CSS.

Or the other option could be that I just layer the preceding div to cover over that part of iframe. But other than hacks (which I am still open to), I imagine that there is a way within best practices.

My page in question is viewable at http://jgallardo.me/home/education/

Comment: Is there a reason that you are trying to use an iFrame? Do you plan on having people interact with the code school report card?

Comment: Take a look at this other Stack Overflow question:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: @Swordfish0321 The reason that I am using an iFrame is because the other option would be to just display an image. But with the iFrame, my "report card" can be viewed live. Also, i want to give them the option to check out Codeschool [link](http://codeschool.com)

Comment: What do you mean by "live", will your report card be changing over time time? If not, you're just creating more work for yourself. Tt will probably be better to just upload an image and wrap an anchor tag around it.

Comment: Yes @Swordfish0321, as I complete classes it will change. By adding the link in the iframe, i just add the link once. As opposed to updating with new screenshots every time I finish classes with Code School.

Comment: Well then the only solutions, to my knowledge, would be to either implement the js solution above (which is kind of jittery), or just z-index it under a preceding div which is kinda of ghetto too, but will solve your issue.