# Difference between contentDocument and contentWindow javascript iframe/frame access properties

Tags: javascript, iframe, frame

- What is the difference between these two properties (contentDocument and contentWindow)?
- Is there any difference in the way they acces the content in the
  frame/iframe?
- Is there any performance issues?
- Should I use `contentXXXXX.document.getElementsBy...` or 
  `contentXXXXX.getElementsBy...`?

I've been searching around in the web but haven't found too much information and before I did a big research I thought I could ask the great community here at stackoverflow. As a comment I'm doing a script that counts inputs on a web page, accessing all levels of frames or iframes and adding those inputs found inside the frames/iframes to the global count. All content is supposed to be from the same domain so no there should be no problems with same-origin-policy, I believe. For the script I'm using pure JavaScript no jQuery or any frameworks/libraries that make life easier u_u jaja. This is a practice script and if anyone would like a look at the code I'll post it, no problem. Thanks for anyone who takes the time to explain this!

Answer (score 83, accepted):

I think the [`<iframe>` MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#Scripting) explains it well:

> With the DOM [`HTMLIFrameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement) object, scripts can **access the `window` object of the framed resource via the [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow) property**. The [`contentDocument`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentDocument) property refers to the document inside the `<iframe>`, **same as `contentWindow.document`**.
>
> From the inside of a frame, a script can get a reference to its parent window with [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent).
>
> Script access to a frame's content is **subject to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy)**. Scripts cannot access most properties in other window objects if the script was loaded from a different origin...

So you would use `contentWindow` the same way you use `window` and `contentDocument` as you use `document`.

Also note how it relates to the [`frames` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/frames)

> `window.frames[0]` **is the same thing as** `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow`

So these statements are true:

```js
// the window property refers to itself https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/window
window.frames[0] 
=== window.frames[0].window;

// the frames' window *is the same* as contentWindow
window.frames[0].window
=== document.querySelector("iframe").contentWindow;

// the frames' document *is the same* as contentDocument
window.frames[0].window.document
=== document.querySelector("iframe").contentDocument;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I should start looking more closely at the documentation. Thanks for the links it's actually really clear.

Comment: I tried it out and I can't make the documentation work 5 years later. My CodePen is https://codepen.io/david263/pen/GwPgwL .

Comment: My IE 11 doesn't have the contentDocument property

Comment: There are cases where `contentDocument` and `contentWindow.document` give different results, so be careful ([example](https://i.imgur.com/extk2Ww.png)). Use `contentDocument` to be on the safe side.

Comment: @thdoan this happens only for a Cross Domain iframe. For same domain iframe both are fine.