# How to just scroll the iframe but not its parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Current my page has a menu bar and iframe section to load the items in the menu bar when clicked. I wanted the iframe to scroll but not the parent page (i want the menu bar fixed to the top).

But the parent page scroll as well. So I set `position: fixed` for the parent page, the Content below can only be scrolled to a point and will eventually be cut off (see image below). How do I resolve this issue?

[image]

Comment: code? fiddle? anything?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `display: table`, flex would be another way.

```css
html,
body { height: 100%; margin: 0 }

.container {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-row {
  display: table-row;
  height: 0;
}
.page-row-expanded {
    height: 100%;
}

main iframe {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}

.header {
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <header class="page-row">
      <div class="header">
        Navigation bar
      </div>
    </header>
            
    <main class="page-row page-row-expanded">
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/"></iframe>
    </main>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Yup it works. Sorry for the delay, i was taking sometime to figure out why it doesn't work, then end up forgot to accept ur ans. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

I dont know if its more complicated because of

```
position:fixed;
```

but have a look over here: [Scroll Down iFrame - jQuery/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150201/scroll-down-iframe-jquery-js)