# passing selectInput to html tag

Tags: javascript, html, r, shiny

I have a html tag `tags$a(href='mailto:email@helloWorld.com?subject=myReport&body=practice level = input$pe', "Click here!")` and I want to pass input$pe inside my tag. But right now, I just get raw text. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does `tags$a(href=paste0('"mailto:email@helloWorld.com?subject=myReport&body=practice level=",input$pe,"'"), "Click here!")` or something similar work. May need to change slightly to get the levels of quoting to cooeprate.

Answer (score 3):

You can use paste0:

`tags$a(paste0("href='mailto:email@helloWorld.com?subject=myReport&body=practice level = ", input$pe,"'"), "Click here!")`

If `input$pe = abc`:

```
<a>
  href='mailto:email@helloWorld.com?subject=myReport&amp;body=practice level = abc'
  Click here!
</a>
```

Comment: HI Florian, thanks for the quick response. But the result is plain text instead of being rendered to HTML.

Comment: Hi Akbar, maybe take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875943/display-html-file-in-shiny-app). Does that solve your issue?