# showing saved HTML plots in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly

I have a lot of plots saved in a folder and their format is *.html so they could be easily viewed in a browser. Plots were made using plotly in R. I want to build a Shiny app to view these saved files. Does anyone know how to read and view these files into Shiny? 
I know the other alternative is to plot on demand in Shiny, but due to the large number of data points and time to generate plots, I want to use the saved files. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `?includeHTML()`

try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875943/display-html-file-in-shiny-app

Comment: Thanks, it works. I tried to use it before, but I was passing it through a plot and it wasn't working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display HTML file in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875943/display-html-file-in-shiny-app)

Comment: Also have you tried saving your plots just as images, like `png` perhaps? Not really much different, but the result may be cleaner.