# Create a basic Shiny app with a dynamic HTML file

Tags: r, shiny

Based on the code below, how can I create a app out of an interactive HTML file? Currently, I am getting a blank app. The HTML file sits in the same folder (also set as the working directory) as the `app` file, do I need to put the HTML file in a separate `www` folder?

I already looked at [Display HTML file in Shiny App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875943/display-html-file-in-shiny-app) and [How can I display a local html file in Shiny UI dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55337502/how-can-i-display-a-local-html-file-in-shiny-ui-dynamically)?

```
library(shiny)

    ui <- fluidPage(
      htmlOutput("infographic")
    )
    
    server <- function(input,output){
      output$infographic <- renderUI({
        tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", 
                    src= "O:/psd/sbaloch/InfographicShinyAPp/Infographic/Hub_Infographic.html",
                    width=800, 
                    height=800)
      })
    }
    
    shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Approach 2 also returns a empty blank app

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  htmlOutput("infographic")
)


server = function(input, output, session){
  output$infographic <- renderUI({
    includeHTML("O:/psd/sbaloch/InfographicShinyAPp/Infographic/Hub_Infographic.html")
    # HTML(readLines(file_to_show))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The difference between your code and those in the links you provided is that you forgot to include the `mainPanel` in `ui`. Essentially, there is no connection between the user interface and the `server`.

Comment: Can you please put your answer in a code? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Embedding `htmlOutput` in `navbarPage` fixed the blank app issue.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinythemes)

ui = fluidPage(
  navbarPage(htmlOutput("infographic"),
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$infographic <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", 
                src= "Hub_Infographic.html",
                width=800, 
                height=800)
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```