# Display HTML File with working Sub-Links in R Shiny App

Tags: html, r, shiny, shinydashboard

I try to display an existing HTML file as content in my R Shiny Dashboard App - similar as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875943/display-html-file-in-shiny-app). My HTML file also contains links to other local HTML files I would like to be able to click and follow as well.

I setup the minimal example as below. If I click the link in **main.html**, I want **target.html** to be displayed. Currently, when I click the link in **main.html**, I get a **Not Found** error.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Jonathan

**main.html**

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>Head</title></head>
<body><a href="target.html">target</a></body>
</html>
```

**target.html**

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/><title>Head</title></head>
<body><a href="main.html">back to main</a></body>
</html>
```

**ui.R**

```
library(shinydashboard)

dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "HTML Main"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("Main", tabName = "main")
        )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(tabName = "main",
                fluidRow(box(width=NULL, htmlOutput("html_main")))
            )
        )
    )
)
```

**server.R**

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  getPageMain<-function() {
    return(includeHTML("C:/sub_link/main.html"))
  }
  output$html_main<-renderUI({getPageMain()})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an **iframe**. This requires to set `target = "_self"` in the **a** tags. The html files must be in the **www** subfolder.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "HTML Main"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Main", tabName = "main")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "main",
              tags$iframe(src = "main.html")
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

***main.html***

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Head</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="target.html" target="_self">target</a>
</body>
</html>
```

***target.html***

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <title>Head</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="main.html" target="_self">back to main</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the iFrame stays blank for me. Not sure why.