# How can I link to a middle of a page, in someone else's site - with no anchor or id?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I would like to link to a second H2 on a different site, so when clicking on my link will automatically scroll to a specific paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible. There is no default parameter or something for that, right?

Perhaps you should try it with an iframe, [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript)