# iFrame Default Scroll Position

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an iFrame in my HTML code sourcing a merch website, but I want it to display by default a little scrolled down because the content on the top is generic and is not what I want them to see at first. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: do you have any source code to demonstrate what you have?

Comment: Same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript