# Combine 2 onload commands in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

So i have an i frame

```
<iframe onload='window.top.scrollTo(0,0);' scrolling='no' src='http://link.me/en/' />
```

and on this iframe i would like to ad also

```
<iframe onload='resizeIframe(this)' scrolling='no' src='http://link.me/en/' />
```

I have tried:

```
<iframe onload='window.top.scrollTo(0,0);resizeIframe(this)' scrolling='no' src='http://link.me/en/' />
```

but is not working.

How can i combine

`onload='resizeIframe(this)'` and `onload='window.top.scrollTo(0,0);'` in the same i frame?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Define a function for the onLoad event and do all of your work in there.

```
<script>
    function onIframeLoad(el) {
        resizeIframe(el);
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
</script>
<iframe onload='onIframeLoad(this)' scrolling='no' src='http://link.me/en/' />
```

Comment: Thnx for your comment. I know this solution but i was wondering if there is a solution without defining a function.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: exception is thrown before `resizeIframe` is executed (probably by `window.top.scrollTo(0,0)`)

```html
<iframe onload='console.log("xx"); window.top.scrollTo(0,0); console.log("yy"); console.log("zz")' scrolling='no' src='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page' />
```

Below is example with no problem

```html
<iframe onload='console.log("xx"); console.log("yy"); console.log("zz")' scrolling='no' src='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page' />
```

Comment: Hi Kamil! I'm doing this onload='console.log("window.top.scrollTo(0,0)"); console.log("resizeIframe(this)")' but is not working. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I copy your code and it works (two lines in console appears), however when you type `'console.log("window.top.scrollTo(0,0)")` you will only see text on console, the scroll will be not executed . If our page is on the same domain, for scroll you can try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/1229832/860099: `onload="resizeIframe(this); this.contentWindow.document.documentElement.scrollTop=0; "`

Comment: @JohnGrischam so if in your case the instruction `window.top.scrollTo(0,0)` raise exception - then currently the best choice is to drop it.