# Scrolling to an element inside a frame

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, puppeteer, playwright

I am currently attempting tests with playwright. I have a website where the DOM elements are inside a frame.

I have attemped to create a scrollIntoView function that gets the selector and scrolls into the view, but it does not seem to work.

How can i scroll to an element inside the frame?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript might help.

Comment: Did you try https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.2.1&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=elementhandlescrollintoviewifneededoptions ?