# open websites in multiple windows and scroll them down using powershell

Tags: powershell

I want to open 4 websites in different windows on one screen and then scroll them down a little. So far I used Powershell to open, size and place them on the screen but I can't figure out how to scroll them down. Help would be appreciated. Here's what I have so far...

```
$ie1 = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie1.navigate("http://www.xe.com/ja/currencycharts/?from=USD&to=JPY&view=12h")
$ie1.visible = $true    
$ie1.top = 0
$ie1.width = 800
$ie1.height = 500
$ie1.Left = 0

$ie2 = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie2.navigate("http://www.xe.com/ja/currencycharts/?from=CNY&to=JPY&view=12h")
$ie2.visible = $true    
$ie2.top = 0
$ie2.width = 800
$ie2.height = 500
$ie2.Left = $ie1.left + $ie2.width

$ie3 = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie3.navigate("http://www.xe.com/ja/currencycharts/?from=THB&to=JPY&view=12h")
$ie3.visible = $true    
$ie3.top = 500
$ie3.width = 800
$ie3.height = 500
$ie3.Left = 0 

$ie4 = new-object -comobject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie4.navigate("http://www.xe.com/ja/currencycharts/?from=USD&to=MXN&view=12h")
$ie4.visible = $true    
$ie4.top = 500
$ie4.width = 800
$ie4.height = 500
$ie4.left = $ie3.left + $ie4.width
```

Comment: Does it have to be Powershell? Do you need to have the 4 browser windows for something? Perhaps one browser showing the 4 web pages in 4 iframes (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp) would be more concise for the screen real estate. Then you could also scroll each of the pages using this hint: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript

Comment: try to use selenium api module for PowerShell https://github.com/adamdriscoll/selenium-powershell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have the pages scroll down using the Document.ParentWindow which has methods `Scroll(x,y)`, `ScrollTo(x,y)` and `ScrollBy(x,y)`.

Below I'm using ScrollBy() (for brevity only on one of the windows, but for the others it is the same thing)

```
$scrollDownValue = 300  # just a wild guess, must be an integer value

$ie1 = New-Object -ComObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie1.Visible = $true    
$ie1.Top     = 0
$ie1.Width   = 800
$ie1.Height  = 500
$ie1.Left    = 0
$ie1.Navigate("http://www.xe.com/ja/currencycharts/?from=USD&to=JPY&view=12h")
# wait for it..
while ($ie1.Busy -and $ie1.ReadyState -ne 4) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

$ie1.Document.ParentWindow.ScrollBy(0, $scrollDownValue)

# important: release the COM object(s) when done
$null = [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($ie1)
[System.GC]::Collect()
[System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```