# How to set iframe content scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an iframe and I want to set the scroll position to that

```
<iframe id="quraniframe" width="100%" height="1100px" src="https://quran.com/1?locale=fa" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

and this is my JavaScript code's

```
    $(function() {

        $('#quraniframe').contents().scrollTo(0, 30);
        window.alert("scroll = " + scroll);
})
```

and this is result in an alert

scroll = undefined

Actually, I use this code to and no effect in iframe content

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrolling an iframe with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192228/scrolling-an-iframe-with-javascript)

Comment: `scroll` will be undefined, unless it's declared somewhere