# Iframe start possition only by HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, web, iframe

I am strugeling for few days on "How to set custom view point in iframe."

I have also tryed ChatGPT, but nothing worked for me.

Point what i am trying to do is that the my friend lost his credentials to db and also to webhosting to change simple thing like phone number on website. So i created exact copy of web. And now I have strugle to get an content of one page to another.

On main page is content which i want to get by iFrame but is nearly on the end of the page is there any option to do such a thing only by HTML and CSS and if yes how? Becouse i am really out of ideas...

Thanks,
Jiri

On main page is content which i want to get by iFrame but is nearly on the end of the page...
I have tryed this:

```
<iframe src="https://ustrasku.cz/index.php?#dayMenu" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="650" title="screen1"></iframe>
```

#dayMenu by this i tryed to aim exact class

And i expected to get that content...

Comment: <iframe src="https://ustrasku.cz/index.php?#dayMenu" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="650" id="innerdiv" title="screen1"></iframe>

Comment: Is there an element in the target HTML with an `id` value of `dayMenu`?  What happens when you try this same approach using a known `id` on that page?

Comment: Unfortunately no, its web genereted by Yii2 framework

Comment: You could potentially [scroll the iframe in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1192228/328193).

Comment: You're better off helping your friend fix his credentials issues than hacking this together. Also, you are probably not going to be allowed to interact with the iframe anyway.

Comment: it´s probably best way, but i still want to try it in HTML and CSS only.... I dont want to care about anything until i have done whole new web for him with all background things.

Answer (score 0):

If a page contains an element with an **id** of `dayMenu`, you can scroll to it by appending `#dayMenu` to the web address. However, the page you are linking to does not contain such an element. It contains an element with a **class** of `dayMenu`, which is a different thing.

However, work is being done on a [new standard](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/) to make it possible to scroll to and/or highlight any specified word or phrase in a page. The major browsers (Chrome, Safari and Edge) have implemented this draft standard already. Firefox has not yet done so.

The following link should work in the major browsers; it should take you to the right page and scroll down to make the menu visible. I have not tested it in an `iframe`, but there is a good chance it will work.

**https://ustrasku.cz/index.php#:~:text=denní%20menu**

You’ll need to copy this link text and paste it into another browser tab in order to test it. If I make it a real link, Stack Overflow escapes the tilde, which breaks the link.

Comment: In browser it seems fine, but in iframe it does nothing. And yet i am nearly done with new web and some webapp based on python for him. But thanks for response. :)